# Editing a passage

Tags: compound-nouns

Below is a passage given in a school test for editing errors:

> Juliane, along with her friends, board(a) Lansa Flight 508 again to
> visit the **crash site**(b). In the plane, she sees(c) two young men
> talking quite loudly. They talk(d) very loudly that they disturb(e)
> the other passengers. Neither the passengers nor the airhostess
> like(f) their behaviour. The air hostess politely said, "You would
> rather kept(g) quiet and fasten your seat belts so that the plane can
> take off."

What is the error in *crash site*?

Comment: If you post your question on the main site, include your corrections and explain you have identified the errors in the text but you are stuck on this one. I don't blame you, unless there is some missing context, it's difficult to understand why any passenger may want to visit a *crash* site. EDITED I see, it's based on a true story https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LANSA_Flight_508

Comment: Are you sure the text says *You would rather (keep) quiet*? I would say that "**We** would rather **you** keep quiet..." fits better.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Yes, the text says so. (Your version sounds better, but the expression 'would rather' should be followed by a simple past verb when there are two subjects, as in your wording - we and you, right? What about this usage of **very** and **that** in the sentence (a result clause) : *They talk(d) very loudly that they disturb(e) the other passengers*? Does it sound natural to the native speakers of English?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was thinking of something else while I was writing. The verb should be in the simple past: “*We would rather you **kept quiet** and fasten your seatbelts*”...  I still think the original doesn't make much, if any, sense. The "very" and "that" example is OK but I'd go for "*They talked **so loudly**....passengers*"

Comment: Why do you think there is an error?